# Adding a MATLAB GUI to a MATLAB code

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am asked by my professor to add a GUI for my Matlab code. My program receives an image as an input and returns a string.

The GUI should enable me to browse the image and then display it. Then I need to use that image in the Matlab code.

To browse and display the image, I created a `pushbutton` control and wrote the following in its callback

```
[baseFileName, folder] = uigetfile('*.jpg');
fullFileName = [folder baseFileName];
rgbImage = imread(fullFileName,'jpg');
imshow(rgbImage);
```

I added a second `pushbutton` and the Matlab code (which has a file name main.m) inside its callback. This function needs the image displayed above as an input, and its output (which is a string) needs to be displayed in the GUI.

I am facing a few problems:

1. I want the image to be displayed in a specific position.
2. How can I call the function in the push button?
3. How can I access and use the image in the first push button to the second push button?

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials out there. Took me just few hours to learn: http://www.mathworks.com/videos/creating-a-gui-with-guide-68979.html

Comment: I'd recommend a [programmatic GUI](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/about-the-simple-programmatic-gui-example.html) rather than GUIDE.

Answer (score 0):

Some hints on how you can get started with your problems:

1. You could create an *axes* object in your figure, whose position can be defined. then just plot the image on that axes. Do all that in the callback
2. Calling a function from a callback should not be a problem
3. Save the image in structure, then you can use for example setappdata and getappdata to pass it between callbacks, i.e. when your figure handle is *h.fig* and your structure called *d*:

   ```
   setappdata(h.fig,'d',d)
   ```

   in the first callback, and to retrieve it, in the second:

   ```
   d = getappdata(h.fig,'d');
   ```